# moving html element from #div to body syntax issue

Tags: jquery, html, prepend

i am trying to 'clone' an element and delete old, i want to do this because I have a z-index problem in IE and will do it using conditional comments:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            var callCenter = $('#callCenter').html();
            alert(callCenter);
            $('#callCenter').remove();
            $('body').prepend("<div id='callCenter'>"+callCenter+"</div>");
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

the problem is that the alert shows something like (without "" )

[image]

So the clasenames are kind of lost

`<span class=clasname>` instead of `<span class="clasname">`

-EDIT-

Trying with

```
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#callCenter').prependTo('body');
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

is this a internet explorer thing?

Comment: How are they lost? Looks like they're still there.

Comment: What's your problem? Move the `alert()` behind the `remove()` to see, whether `var callCenter` has the appropriate content. It doesn't matter if there are quotes around the attributes – the alert-box-contents are what MS IE makes out of the HTML while parsing it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {            
            var callCenter = $('#callCenter').remove().prependTo(document.body);
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```